# How do I resolve a NETSDK1022 compiler error in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have a Visual Studio 2022 .NetCore C# solution containing multiple projects. We've run into an issue where the VS build complains about finding multiple same named files across several of the projects.

**This is the error message I get:**

> Error NETSDK1022  Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK
> includes 'Compile' items from your project directory by default.  You
> can either remove these items from your project file, or set the
> 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to
> explicitly include them in your project file.  The duplicate items
> were: 'obj\Debug\net7.0\common\SomeFileName.cs'

If we build using Rider, we do not see these errors.

How do I resolve these issues? Are there project/solution file settings?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the same file was added to the same project multiple times, not the same file in multiple projects.

SDK style projects include files into the project that are present in the project directory. If the same file is also explicitly added to the project, that can cause the error.

Is this a .csproj file that was generated by Rider?

See [NETSDK1022: Duplicate items were included.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1022) and note that if you edit the project file and add the following you can disable the behavior of adding files to the `Compile` collection.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
</PropertyGroup>
```

With this property set to `false` all of the .cs source files will need to be explicitly added to the project.

Alternatively remove the explicit include of the file in the error message.

Comment: adding that to offending project file resulted in the following new compiler error: Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point...  It did in fact clean up the NETSDK1022 error though....

Comment: Is the class with Main part of the project? You will need to explicitly add all the .cs source files.

Comment: @JonathanDodds - Not sure what you mean by "Explicitly add all the source files." Do you mean editing the project file by hand to include the source files?

Comment: @JohnB No. In Visual Studio you can right-click the project and Add... -> Existing Item

Comment: @JohnB Are you using Rider 2023.1 and is it configured to use MSBuild v17 from VS 2022?

Comment: @JonathanDodds - This is a generated file from gRPC  compile and live in the obj\Debug\net7.0\common folders of the offending projects.

Comment: @JohnB [grpc/grpc-dotnet](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet)? Can you share an example of a generated project file? Or is there an example in the docs for gRPC?